# Reading custom resource from within MIDP 2.0 midlet

Tags: resources, midp

How can one load custom (not an image, nor a sound file) resource file from /res within .jar using MIDP 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working with MIDP 2.1, but I hope this is in 2.0 too.

Class.getResource(path_to_resource) should give you an InputStream to the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
getResourceAsStream("/res/yourresource");
```